# Am I running NetworkManager or networkd?

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan, systemd-networkd

I am learning to use netplan. When writing a YAML configuration file I need to know which renderer to use, either NetworkManager or networkd.

How do I know if I am running NetworkManager or networkd?

Comment: What does this suggest? `sudo service network-manager status`

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop the output is suggesting that Network Manager is used. On my Ubuntu 18.04 Server the output is "`Unit network-manager.service could not be found`".
Is this really the only way to determine which networking daemon that is beeing used?

Comment: No; see my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: although `network-manager.service could not be found` was what I got, NetworkManager.service was to be found and apparently they are the same: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031439/am-i-running-networkmanager-or-networkd?newreg=699d61928a9b46e294d2f0bdba3588fc#comment1678036_1031439

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu desktop version ships with Network Manager. In most desktop environments, it does a good job. In this case, the netplan file should hand over networking to Network Manager. Typically, the relevant file is `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`  It reads:

```
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

In Ubuntu server edition, since no desktop environment is installed by default; i.e. Gnome, Unity, Wayland, KDE, etc., Network Manager is not possible and therefore not installed. In versions 17.10 and later, networking is handled by netplan alone. The typical relevant file is `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` It usually reads:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
```

...where enp0s3 is your relevant interface. This will allow an internet connection by DHCP until a full and further configuration can be effected by editing the yaml file and following with:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Regarding "In versions 17.10 and later, networking is handled by netplan alone.",  isn't it handled by netplan together with networkd and not netplan alone?

Comment: netplan instead of the earlier `/etc/network/interfaces`. Both have many supporting bits and pieces but the files I mention here are all that need be used to effect networking.

Comment: "since no desktop environment is installed [ ... ] Network Manager is not possible" well CentOS is doing just fine with `nmcli` and `nmtui` on servers, so definitely possible.

Comment: @kubanczyk  `nmcli` is certainly possible here; however, why does one need it? Set your details in netplan and be done.

Answer (score 41):

As near as I can tell, there have been 3 approaches to networks in Linux:

**1)** The oldest uses the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and `ifup`/`ifdown` scripts to manage these interfaces.

**2)** After that came the `network-manager` daemon (often written `Network-Manager`) which has GUI interfaces available.

**3)** And most recently the `systemd-networkd` daemon (sometimes abbreviated just 'networkd') which is based on `systemd` unit files.

---

To see how your network is being managed, first you must know if you're system is initializing with `systemd` or the older `init` as it's first process.  *(Debian and Ubuntu, for example now use `systemd` instead of `init`).*

You can check if your system uses `systemd` with [this](https://linuxhandbook.com/check-if-systemd/):

```
ps  -p 1  -o comm=     # i.e. -p = process # 1, -o = output column 'comm' or the command name, & the '=' is to not display column name
```

---

So if you are NOT running `systemd`, then clearly you can rule out `systemd-networkd`.

If you ARE running `systemd`, then check which network service daemons are running with these two commands:

```
sudo service systemd-networkd status
sudo service network-manager  status   # before Ubuntu V21.10
sudo service NetworkManager   status   # after  Ubuntu V21.10!
```

You'll see either `Active: active (running)` or `Active: inactive (dead)` reported for each one.

Note that you can also run these newer commands, but obviously if you don't have systemd, they won't work for you:

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd
systemctl status network-manager   # before Ubuntu V21.10
systemctl status NetworkManager    # after  Ubuntu V21.10!
```

---

**But you're not done yet...**

Finally, even if one of these two daemons are running, that doesn't mean your network hardware interfaces are being managed by them, as there are exceptions.

First any interfaces defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` are ignored by the network-manager package.  *(`man 5 NetworkManager`)*

Next, `systemd-networkd` will only manage network addresses and routes for any link for which it finds a .network file with an appropriate `[Match]` section.  *(`man 8 systemd-networkd`)*.

---

! Ref: [Service name change occurred: from `network-manager` to `NetworkManager`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371275/where-has-the-network-manager-service-in-21-10-gone).

Comment: Can there be a situation where there are network-manager and systemd-networkd be running at the same time?

Comment: @Эдуард Мартыненко
 this might help: https://www.xmodulo.com/switch-from-networkmanager-to-systemd-networkd.html

Comment: @ЭдуардМартыненко Probably not out of the box, but possible. Each of them should work with their own set of network interfaces only. See last part of this answer.

Comment: That method of checking if your system using systemd is incorrect and will give the wrong answer on modern Debian systems because on modern Debian /sbin/init is a symlink to /lib/systemd/systemd.

Comment: @user2108462 Fixed:  Thanks for reporting this.  Found better method in the Linux Handbook and edited my answer above to use it instead.

Answer (score 5):

Since Feb 2023, Netplan release [0.106](https://github.com/canonical/netplan/releases/tag/0.106), `netplan status` has been introduced, which pretty prints a lot of information, including the currently used renderer. The output below is taken from a bare Ubuntu 23.04 installation:

```
$ netplan status
     Online state: online
    DNS Addresses: 127.0.0.53 (stub)
       DNS Search: <redacted>

●  1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Addresses: 127.0.0.1/8
                   ::1/128
           Routes: ::1 metric 256

●  2: enp0s1 ethernet UP (networkd: enp0s1)
      MAC Address: <redacted> (<redacted>)
        Addresses: 192.168.64.2/24 (dhcp)
                   fd88:4b93:b031:f03e:80f0:d4ff:fe4f:15d3/64
                   fe80::80f0:d4ff:fe4f:15d3/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.64.1
                   fe80::6c7e:67ff:fe8c:8364
       DNS Search: <redacted>
           Routes: default via 192.168.64.1 from 192.168.64.2 metric 100 (dhcp)
                   192.168.64.0/24 from 192.168.64.2 metric 100 (link)
                   192.168.64.1 from 192.168.64.2 metric 100 (dhcp, link)
                   fd88:4b93:b031:f03e::/64 metric 100 (ra)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256
```

You can see that the main NIC `enp0s1` is being managed by `networkd`.

After installing the `network-manager` package and setting the default renderer to `NetworkManager`, this is the only line that makes a difference in `netplan status`:

`●  2: enp0s1 ethernet UP (unmanaged)`

The main NIC `enp0s1` is being managed by `NetworkManager` now.

Comment: This is a really nice addition. Too bad it isn't yet in Ubuntu 22.04, but thanks for bringing this to our knowledge. 

Comment: This will be so helpful when it makes it into ubuntu 